# Is there a way to move both the nested parent element and child element, in SortableJS?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable, sortablejs

## My Requirements

1. Only the children can have handles to move them around and re-sort inside of the correct Group
2. Children from other groups can not mix
3. When the child goes past its group it needs to switch from moving the child element to moving the parent element

↕️ = symbolizing what the user is dragging

```
Group A
  A_foo
  A_bar
  
Group B
  B_baz
  B_qux
  
Group C
  C_john
  C_tim
```

## ❌Wrong

```
Group A
  A_bar
  
Group B
  A_foo ↕️ (❌ child moved into the wrong group and didn't move the parent)
  B_baz
  B_qux
  
Group C
  C_john
  C_tim
```

## ✔️ Correct

```
Group B
  B_baz
  B_qux

Group A (✔️ instead of moving just the child it moved the whole parent)
  A_bar
  A_foo ↕️
  
Group C
  C_tim
  C_john ↕️ (✔️ children are still able to rearranged )
```

1. I have tried using more than one handle on an element, while restricting where parents and children can go.
2. I have tried replacing the innerHTML of the dragged element to the parents HTML. However that resulted in a mess of duplicating the parent into the child position. It looked something like this.

```
Group B
  Group A
    A_foo ↕️
    A_bar
  B_baz
  B_qux
  
Group C
  C_john
  C_tim
```

3. I have tried using multiDrag to select both the child and parent element however that did not work.

I feel like I must be missing something simple in SortableJS